# CSS Image Slider is slightly misaligned

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an image slider on a website I am currently working on:

http://scientized.com/ (first part on the main page)

As you can see it works beautifully. Now I am trying to put the same image slider on a page:

http://scientized.com/mathematics/

As you can see it becomes slightly misaligned. The images do not slide edge to edge. I have been at for some hours now and cant seem to find where the problem is occurring.

- It is a wordpress site, and the slider is a widget I've been working on.
- All content is currently dummy content  - don't read too much into it.

Anyone can spot the error in my css code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ul` has a margin on it on the faulty page. Change to this ...

```
.entry-content ul {
  margin-left: 0 ;
}
```

But be aware it will affect other ul on Wordpress pages. Target a different class if possible.

EDIT: it's in your code as `.entry-content ul ul`

EDIT 2: you can target .slides, like this:

```
.slides {
   margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: add .slides {margin-left: 0;}

Comment: Check in dev tools. It works if you remove margin on either ul or .slides.